# Event-driven Elastic Transcoder?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Is there a way to setup a transcoding pipeline on AWS such that it automatically transcodes any new files uploaded to a particular S3 bucket, and places them in another bucket?

I know there is a REST API, and that in theory the uploader could also issue a REST request to the transcoder after it has uploaded the file, but for a variety of reasons, this isn't really an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can now be accomplished using [AWS Lambda](http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).

Lambda basically allows you to trigger/run scripts based off of events. You could easily create a Lambda script that runs as soon as a new file is uploaded to a designated s3 bucket. The script would then start a transcoding job for that newly uploaded video file.

This is literally one of the example use cases provided in the Lambda documentation.

Comment: That's better now. See SO has policy and it creates a review queue for such an answer which are direct to a link instead of detail description. So your answer was in a queue. in future try to avoid such answer, at least provide more info related to link and then add link for reference only.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I heard about Lambda when it came out. We actually found a way to remove transcoding entirely from the pipeline, but glad to see there is now a solution. Last I heard though, Lambda was still only available in us-east-1 (N. Virginia), and possibly us-west-2 (Oregon).